# Множественный переключатель jQuery

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

1) Столкнулся с такой плюшкой, что кнопка "Выключить/Включить" работает только одна, если ещё на этой странице сделать такую же кнопку с таким же классом, то работать не будет одна из них, а точнее та которая находиться второй по счету. Мне требуется исправить, так, чтобы все работали кнопки хоть их 1000 с этими же классами.

2) Так же нужно что бы при нажатии на кнопку какую-либо из них выполнялся php код. 
т.е я думаю через AJAX сделать, разумеется без перезагрузки страницы. Пробовал делать на следующем примере: [перейти](http://ajaxs.ru/lesson/ajax/127-dinamicheskaja_podgruzka_dannyh_na_stranicu.html) (ajaxs.ru), но не получилось, просто не работает кнопка.

Код HTML кнопки:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="switch_state">Выключить</button>
```

Код jQuery моего скрипта:

```
$('#switch_state').on('click', function(){
if ($(this).hasClass('btn btn-danger')) {
    $(this).removeClass('btn btn-danger').addClass('btn btn-success').html("Включить")
    return }
$(this).removeClass('btn btn-success').addClass('btn btn-danger').html('Выключить')
;});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дам наводку: без JS - делаете кнопку, в onclick делаете запрос на AJAX, а запрос уже будет обрабатывать то что между button и переключать, определять какую именно кнопку менять будет по ID которую вы тоже будете подавать в действии onclick.

Comment: мне нужно исправить только этот код.